# How can i estimate the covariance for Gaussian HMM?

Tags: machine-learning, hidden-markov-model

I am trying to train the gaussian Hidden Markov Model (HMM) for my thesis problem.  I am exteding hmm code from the [guyz](https://github.com/guyz/HMM) implementaion

Here is the code to reestimate mean and co-variance.

```
def _reestimateMixtures(self,observations,gamma_mix):
    '''
    Helper method that performs the Baum-Welch 'M' step
    for the mixture parameters - 'w', 'means', 'covars'.
    '''        
    w_new = numpy.zeros( (self.n,self.m), dtype=self.precision)
    means_new = numpy.zeros( (self.n,self.m,self.d), dtype=self.precision)
    covars_new = [[ numpy.matrix(numpy.zeros((self.d,self.d), dtype=self.precision)) for j in xrange(self.m)] for i in xrange(self.n)]
    
    for j in xrange(self.n):
        for m in xrange(self.m):
            numer = []
            denom = []                
            for t in xrange(len(observations)):
                for k in xrange(self.m):
                    denom.append(self._eta(t,len(observations)-1)*gamma_mix[t][j][k])
                numer.append(self._eta(t,len(observations)-1)*gamma_mix[t][j][m])
            
            numer=logsumexp(numer);
            denom=logsumexp(denom);
            w_new[j][m] = numer - denom
        w_new[j] = self._normalize_log(w_new[j])
    for j in xrange(self.n):
        for m in xrange(self.m):
            numer = numpy.zeros( (self.d), dtype=self.precision)
            denom = numpy.zeros( (self.d), dtype=self.precision)
            for t in xrange(len(observations)):
               numer += (self._eta(t,len(observations)-1)*numpy.exp(gamma_mix[t][j][m])*observations[t])
               denom += (self._eta(t,len(observations)-1)*numpy.exp(gamma_mix[t][j][m]))
            means_new[j][m] = numer/denom
           
    cov_prior = [[ numpy.matrix(self.min_std*numpy.eye((self.d), dtype=self.precision)) for j in xrange(self.m)] for i in xrange(self.n)]
    for j in xrange(self.n):
        for m in xrange(self.m):
            numer = numpy.matrix(numpy.zeros( (self.d,self.d), dtype=self.precision))
            denom = numpy.matrix(numpy.zeros( (self.d,self.d), dtype=self.precision))
            for t in xrange(len(observations)):
                vector_as_mat = numpy.matrix( (observations[t]-self.means[j][m]), dtype=self.precision )
                numer += (self._eta(t,len(observations)-1)*numpy.exp(gamma_mix[t][j][m])*numpy.dot( vector_as_mat.T, vector_as_mat))
                denom += (self._eta(t,len(observations)-1)*numpy.exp(gamma_mix[t][j][m]))

            covars_new[j][m] = numer/denom
            covars_new[j][m] = covars_new[j][m] + cov_prior[j][m]
```

Problem is, sometimes the numer and denom in the above code becoming zeros's. As a result my covariance matrix containing all **Nan** values.
Is above code is valid to compute covariance matrix? if yes, how can i handle covarinace not to contain Nan values.